# Memory leak when a WPF control is passed across Application Domain

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, appdomain, wpf-4.0

Our software application needs to create and access a WPF user control in a separate application domain. For this, we used the WPF Add-In architecture. However, we noticed that even after the application domain is unloaded and garbage collection is done, there is a memory leak. This memory leak can be demonstrated by repeatedly creating and destroying the WPF control in the application domain and observing the memory usage in Task Manager.

I have created a very simple test application that demonstrates this issue. The sample project is available in the [shared folder](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9580A1959CFA6E6B!159&authkey=!AOCeoQHGwUg4GdE&ithint=file,.zip)

Comment: Do memory profiling in your application and post the results here.

Comment: I tried memory profiling using ANTS profiler and it just freezes up when I try to take a memory snapshot. I also tried memory profiling using VS2013 and it didn't provide any useful info. I would recommend trying out the sample project provided above and seeing the memory leak firsthand.